# Sitecore 9 Installation error Failed to start 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer'

Tags: service, solr, sitecore9

Hi I am trying to install sitecore 9 using SIF and a powershell script provided with the ELearning Sitecore 9 developer foundations. I've had quite a few issue during this including getting SOLR 6.6.2 setup. I seem to have over come these problems, however one that has stumped me over the last few day is this exception:

```
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Failed to start service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - local.xconnect-IndexWorker (local.xconnect-IndexWorker)'.
At C:\sitecore\install\install.ps1:43 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:02:50
Start-Service : Failed to start service 'Sitecore XConnect Search Indexer - local.xconnect-IndexWorker (local.xconnect-IndexWorker)'.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\2.1.0\Public\Tasks\Invoke-ManageServiceTask.ps1:40 char:33
+                     $instance | Start-Service
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand
```

So far I found some threads on here explaining how they fixed it and giving the error messages from the logs. I have tried a few things although they would appear to have this issue for different reason. For example a common cause of this seems to be that their license has expired or does not include xConnect. I don't believe this is my issue because I am using a license from another sitecore 9 project that uses XConnect that works.

Also the error message in my xconnect logs seems to be different to when this is the case:

```
2019-10-11 18:00:29.419 +01:00 [Information] Starting Xdb Indexer App Domain, Machine: LAPTOP-171, InstanceName: XConnectIndexer_AppDomain
2019-10-11 18:00:30.223 +01:00 [Information] SystemPerformanceCounters Constructor, Instance:XConnectIndexer, Path: App_Data\Diagnostics, CounterFilePattern: *.json
2019-10-11 18:00:31.376 +01:00 [Error] Exception occurred during instantiating of IndexerHost.
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Authority/Host could not be parsed.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrCoreUri.ReplaceCoreName(String newCoreName)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrWriterSettings..ctor(SolrCoreUri coreUri, Int32 maximumUpdateBatchSize, Int32 maximumDeleteBatchSize, Int32 maximumCommitMilliseconds, Int32 parallelizationDegree, Int32 retryCount, Int32 maximumRetryDelayMilliseconds, Encoding encoding, IndexerSettings indexerSettings)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.RebuildSolrWriterSettings..ctor(String rebuildCoreName, SolrWriterSettings solrWriterSettings, Uri rebuildCoreWriteUrl, Uri rebuildCoreCleanUri, Uri rebuildCoreStatusPath, Uri swapCoresUri, Uri coreAdminUrl, Uri rebuildCoreCommitUrl)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.RebuildSolrWriterSettings..ctor(SolrWriterSettings settings, String rebuildCoreName)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrIndexRebuilder.GetRebuildSolrWriterSettings(SolrWriterSettings settings)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Solr.SolrIndexRebuilder..ctor(SolrWriterSettings writerSettings, XdbModel xdbModel)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationServiceType.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<op_Implicit>b__0(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.ConstructorMatcher.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationServiceType.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<op_Implicit>b__0(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.ScopedCallSite.Invoke(ServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerHost..ctor(IConfigurationRoot config) in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\IndexerHost.cs:line 46
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer.IndexerAppDomainHost.IndexerHostAppDomainBridge..ctor() in C:\BA\147b0adf6c2580c7\code\Sitecore.XConnect.Search.Indexer\IndexerAppDomainHost.cs:line 149
```

I did find [a blog post mentioning the error](https://tothecore.sk/2018/08/09/sitecore-xconnect-search-indexer-windows-service-throwing-exception-the-authority-host-could-not-be-parsed/).

But I'm not sure really what his fix is. When I try to run the script with the URL he suggests it then can't establish a connection with SOLR.

I also can't start the server manually through the server manager. I get the same error in the Window event logs.

Below is the script I'm running from the sitecore 9 set up guide.

```
    #define parameters 
    $prefix = "local" 
    $PSScriptRoot = "C:\sitecore\install" 
    $XConnectCollectionService = "$prefix.xconnect" 
    $sitecoreSiteName = "$prefix.sc" 
    $SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr/#" 
    $SolrRoot = "C:\sitecore\install\Solr-6.6.2" 
    $SolrService = "Solr-6.6.2" 
    $SqlServer = "(local)" 
    $SqlAdminUser = "sa" 
    $SqlAdminPassword="kagoolpass01" 
    #install client certificate for xconnect 
    $certParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-createcert.json"     
    CertificateName = "$prefix.xconnect_client" 
    }  
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @certParams -Verbose 

    #install solr cores for xdb 
    $solrParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-solr.json"     
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
    SolrService = $SolrService     
    CorePrefix = $prefix 
    }
    Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 

    #deploy xconnect instance 
    $xconnectParams = @{     
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\xconnect-xp0.json"     
    Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 
   (OnPrem)_xp0xconnect.scwdp.zip"     
   LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
   Sitename = $XConnectCollectionService     
   XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
   SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
   SqlServer = $SqlServer  
   SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
   SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
   SolrCorePrefix = $prefix     
   SolrURL = $SolrUrl      
   } 
   Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams 

   #install solr cores for sitecore 
   $solrParams = @{     
   Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-solr.json"     
   SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
   SolrRoot = $SolrRoot     
   SolrService = $SolrService     
   CorePrefix = $prefix 
   } 
   Install-SitecoreConfiguration @solrParams 

   #install sitecore instance 
   $xconnectHostName = "$prefix.xconnect" 
   $sitecoreParams = @{    
    Path = "$PSScriptRoot\sitecore-XP0.json"      
    `enter code here`Package = "$PSScriptRoot\Sitecore 9.0.0 rev. 171002 
    (OnPrem)_single.scwdp.zip" 
    LicenseFile = "$PSScriptRoot\license.xml"     
    SqlDbPrefix = $prefix  
    SqlServer = $SqlServer  
    SqlAdminUser = $SqlAdminUser     
    SqlAdminPassword = $SqlAdminPassword     
    SolrCorePrefix = $prefix  
    SolrUrl = $SolrUrl     
    XConnectCert = $certParams.CertificateName     
    Sitename = $sitecoreSiteName         
    XConnectCollectionService = "https://$XConnectCollectionService"    
   }
   Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
```

Just wondering if anyone out there, especially Sitecore MVPs that browse Stack Overflow have any insight into why this could be happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SolrUrl in the Sitecore SIF installation should be without #

```
$SolrUrl = "https://localhost:8983/solr"
```

Comment: Hi Jan yeah that's the answer.